# Why the output is 0 after add?

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm

```
       .data
enter: .string "%d"
out:   .string "%d"
n:     .word 0
n2:    .word 0
       .globl count
count: ...
       mov r5, #0 // r5 = 0
       ldr r0,=enter
       ldr r1,=n
       bl scanf
       add r5,r5,r1 // r5 = r5 + r1

       ldr r0,=enter
       ldr r1,=n2
       bl scanf
       add r5,r5,r1 // r5 = r5 + r1
       ldr r0,=out
       mov r1,r5
       bl printf
       ...
```

input `1 2`

I want to add two numbers and stored in `r5` and output.

I don't know why the output is `0`, instead of `3`?

Comment: You forgot to load the inputs. `scanf` obviously reads them into `n` and `n2`. Also `r1` is caller-saved. You need to something like `ldr r0,=n; ldr r1, [r0]; ldr r0,=n2; ldr r0, [r0]; add r1, r1, r0`

Comment: You can get a C compiler to generate working examples for you, if you write C that calls `scanf` and `printf`.  https://godbolt.org/

Comment: @Jester I can't save value into ```r5```? because I have lots of numbers to input and add

Comment: `r5` is ok, but `r1` is clobbered by a call, so should be considered uninitialized after one until you put something meaningful in it.